# How to combine probability values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a simple probability question. I have two variables A, B and C, each can have two values: True and False. I have the following probability values:

P(C = true | A = true), 
P(C = true | A = false), 
P(C = true | B = true),
P(C = true | B = false)

Both A and B are independent. How can I compute the probability of C being true given the values of A and B. That is

P(C = true | A = true, B = true)
P(C = true | A = true, B = false)
P(C = true | A = false, B = true)
P(C = true | A = false, B = false)

What are the methods that I can use here? Can I use the noisy or model? if so, how? Please help me solve this as I am a very beginner to probability theorems. Thank you so much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to compute the mentioned probabilities  on base
of the mentioned data. Here an example where $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ 
provide exactly the same data but different outcomes for the mentioned
probabilities. In the notation $A$ stands for $A\text{=true}$ and
$A^{c}$ for $A\text{=false}$.

$P\left(A\right)=P\left(B\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ and consequently $P\left(A\cap B\right)=\frac{1}{4}$.
Now take $P\left(A\cap B\cap C_{1}\right)=P\left(A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C_{1}\right)=P\left(A\cap B^{c}\cap C_{1}\right)=P\left(A^{c}\cap B\cap C_{1}\right)=\frac{1}{8}$
and $P\left(A\cap B\cap C_{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}=P\left(A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C_{2}\right)\wedge P\left(A\cap B^{c}\cap C_{2}\right)=0=P\left(A^{c}\cap B\cap C_{2}\right)$.

In fact you can also define: $C_{2}=\left(A\cap B\right)\cup\left(A^{c}\cap B^{c}\right)$.

Then for $i=1,2$ we find:

$P\left(C_{i}\mid A\right)=\frac{P\left(A\cap C_{i}\right)}{P\left(A\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$
and $P\left(C_{i}\mid A^{c}\right)=\frac{P\left(A^{c}\cap C_{i}\right)}{P\left(A^{c}\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Likewise $P\left(C_{i}\mid B\right)=P\left(C_{i}\mid B^{c}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$.

However: $P\left(C_{1}\mid A\cap B\right)=\frac{P\left(A\cap B\cap C_{1}\right)}{P\left(A\cap B\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}$
and $P\left(C_{2}\mid A\cap B\right)=\frac{P\left(A\cap B\cap C_{2}\right)}{P\left(A\cap B\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{4}}=1$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you please tell me what else I need to have in order for me to be able to compute the mentioned probabilities? Thx